# Dynamically update area.stacking from normal to null using highchart-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng, stacked-area-chart

I am a very new to highstocks and I am trying to achieve something for which I couldn't find any documentation.

I have a stacked area chart. So at this stage the plotOptions looks

`plotOptions: {
  area: {
    stacking: "normal"
  }
}`

And on a click of a button, I want to change it to

`plotOptions : {
  area: {
    stacking: null (undefined, tried both)
  }
}`

thereby making it a basic area chart. There is no plotOptions update function in highstock and if I try to manually update it, it doesn't work. Any suggestions or ideas as to how I can make this work

Answer (score 0):

Use `chart.update()` to update plotOptions.

```
chart.update({
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: null
    }
  }
})
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v3zcse3w/